# MongoDB query to update date field in an document with another date field plus 1 day

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I am trying to update a **date field** (say nextChargeDate) in multiple documents in a collection with another **date field** (say currentTermEndDate) in the same document **incrementing the currentTermEndDate by 1 day**.

Here's the update function I have written:

db.some_collection.updateMany(

```
{$or: [{_id: ObjectId('5c3e62ef2e9c4e0008f4749f')}, {_id: ObjectId('5c3e635a2e9c4e0008f47852')}, {_id: ObjectId('5c3e63a12e9c4e0008f47ab9')}]},
{
    $set: { **nextChargeDate: new Date({$add: [ "currentTermEndDate", 1*24*60*60000 ]}**)  }
}
```

)

Here's the update looks like in Mongo:

currentTermEndDate:2019-04-04 23:59:59.999

nextChargeDate:1969-12-31 18:00:00.000

It would be very helpful if someone can help with a solution to achieve the desired result which would be:

currentTermEndDate:2019-04-04 23:59:59.999

nextChargeDate:2019-04-05 23:59:59.999

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Update MongoDB field using value of another field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3974985/update-mongodb-field-using-value-of-another-field)

Comment: I went through the information in the above link but that was for a string field and in my case its date field and I need to perform this operation for particular set of documents filtered by the query mentioned above. I am not sure how I can perform aggregation on a particular set of documents and not all. If someone can provide a sample code would help me to better understand. I am new to Mongo DB

Answer (score -1):

You need to take a date as `ISODate("dateField").getTime()`. Try below query:-

```
    {$or: [{_id: ObjectId('5c3e62ef2e9c4e0008f4749f')}, {_id: ObjectId('5c3e635a2e9c4e0008f47852')}, {_id: ObjectId('5c3e63a12e9c4e0008f47ab9')}]},
{
    $set: { "nextChargeDate": new Date(ISODate("currentTermEndDate").getTime()+ 1*24*60*60000)  }
}
```

Comment: Hello @cogent, I tried the query as mentioned above


$set: { nextChargeDate: new Date(ISODate("currentTermEndDate").getTime() + 1*24*60*60000)

But I am getting this error:


2019-02-10T18:13:17.712-0600 E QUERY    [js] Error: invalid ISO date: currentTermEndDate :
ISODate@src/mongo/shell/types.js:65:1

Comment: The date format is `Date` in the DB here's a sample:

currentTermEndDate: 2019-01-16 23:59:59.999
nextChargeDate: 2021-01-18 00:00:00.000